# How long does it normally take to make cyanogenmod for a new phone?

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I know no one can predict the future, but statistically speaking how long has it taken in the past to create cyanogenmod rom? I'm most interested in the Galaxy S7 Edge. According to google, the S6 was released June 12, 2015 and this [xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s6/samsung-galaxy-s-6--s-6-edge-unified-development/cyanogenmod-13-galaxy-s6-t3269984) thread said it was created 2015-12-13, so that's 6 months. Anyone have any more experience or think this reasoning is valid?

Is there any chance the S7 would never get CM or is it only a matter of time?

Comment: The S7 edge already has an alpha version of CyanogenMod 13. If you were to read the thread (and use Google correctly) you would find out that both versions (S6's and S7's CM) are both in a state you would call *unusable*. The issue is missing Kernel sources and documentation and that's why there were nearly a year of *NO* development for CM for the S6.

Comment: Based on the above reason and how S6's development scene is, you might as well project that it will _never_ happen for Exynos variants. Snapdragon ones might have a glimmer of hope, but those are locked down tighter than Exynos ones too.